# How to invoke a generic F# function using reflection?

Tags: f#

I am trying to invoke an F# function using reflection. The function is generic, but it only works for `obj`.

I do not know statically what `'t` will be. I have a `System.Type` object.

How can I configure the type parameter at run-time?

```ml
type Foo<'t> =
  {
    Foo : 't
  }

type Bar<'t> =
  {
    Bar : 't
  }

type Qux<'t> =
  {
    Foo : 't
    Bar : 't
  }

let qux (x : Foo<'t>) (y : Bar<'t>) : Qux<'t> =
  {
    Foo = x.Foo
    Bar = y.Bar
  }

open FSharp.Reflection

let invokeDynamic (fn : obj) (args : obj seq) =
  let rec loop (next : obj) (args : obj list) : obj =
    match args with
    | [] -> next
    | x :: xs ->
      let fnType = next.GetType()
      if FSharpType.IsFunction fnType then
        let methodInfo =
          fnType.GetMethods()
          |> Seq.filter 
            (fun x -> 
              x.Name = "Invoke" 
              && Array.length (x.GetParameters()) = 1)
          |> Seq.head
        let result = methodInfo.Invoke(next, [| x |])
        loop result xs
      else
        failwithf "Object was not of a function type: %s" fnType.FullName
  loop fn (List.ofSeq args)

// 't = obj
// Works
invokeDynamic qux [ box { Foo = box 123 }; box { Bar = box 456 } ]
|> printfn "%A"

// 't = int
// Explodes
invokeDynamic qux [ box { Foo = 123 }; box { Bar = 456 } ]
|> printfn "%A"
```

Comment: You'd have to figure out what the type parameters are from the parameter values, and that's not a trivial job, there's a whole great big compiler for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `invokeDynamic` function is actually working fine. The problem is with the way you're calling it. In particular, the second invocation needs an instantiation of `qux` where `'t` is `int` instead of `obj`. The way to get that is to make `qux`'s type parameter explicit:

```ml
let qux<'t> (x : Foo<'t>) (y : Bar<'t>) : Qux<'t> =
  {
    Foo = x.Foo
    Bar = y.Bar
  }
```

You can then conjure the right version of `qux` for each call:

```ml
invokeDynamic qux<obj> [ box { Foo = box 123 }; box { Bar = box 456 } ]
|> printfn "%A"

invokeDynamic qux<int> [ box { Foo = 123 }; box { Bar = 456 } ]
|> printfn "%A"
```

The compiler would normally do this for you automatically, of course, but you've defeated its ability to infer the type parameter, so you're always instantiating `qux<obj>` by default, and you can't call `qux<obj>` with a `Foo<int>` and `Bar<int>`.

So, to be clear, the compiler won't let you configure the type parameter of an F# function at run-time this way. If you were working with a class method instead, [`MakeGenericMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod) would do what you want, but generic F# functions don't have a similar API (AFAIK).

Comment: I don't know the type `int` or `obj` statically, I only have a `System.Type`. I will update the question.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. See the last paragraph of my answer. If your code has a hard-coded reference to `qux`, then the compiler assumes that `'t` is `obj` statically if it can't infer the actual type. You might have better luck using a class method instead of a plain F# function.

Comment: Yes, I was able to get this working with a helper type and static methods `static method Qux<'t>`